# MobX Invariant failed: Side effects like changing state are not allowed at this point

Tags: react-router, react-bootstrap, mobx, mobx-react

I'm a JS/React/MobX/else newbie, trying to do something very simple without success.

What I want is - 2 buttons, once clicked, show corresponding tab in a modal, using react-bootstrap and mobx.

But I keep getting this error:

**[mobx] Encountered an uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[AuthModal#0.render()] Error: [mobx] Invariant failed: Side effects like changing state are not allowed at this point. Are you trying to modify state from, for example, the render function of a React component? Tried to modify: AuthModalStore@3.tab**

Please help. Much appreciated.

code for the store:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class AuthModalStore {

  @observable show = false;
  @observable tab = 1;

  constructor() {
    this.turnOn = this.turnOn.bind(this);
    this.turnOff = this.turnOff.bind(this);
    this.changeToTab = this.changeToTab.bind(this);
  }

  turnOn(key = 1) {
    console.log('running turnOn');
    this.tab = key;
    this.show = true;
  }

  turnOff() {
    this.show = false;
  }

  changeToTab(key) {
    this.tab = key;
  }

}

const store = new AuthModalStore();

export default store;
```

react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

import AuthModal from './AuthModal';


@inject('authModalStore')
@observer
export default class AuthButtons extends React.Component {

  handleClick(event) {
    var key;
    switch (event.target.innerHTML) {
      case 'Log In':
        key = 1;
        break;
      case 'Sign Up':
        key = 2;
        break;
      default:
        key = 1;
    }
    this.props.authModalStore.turnOn(key);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {/* login / signup buttons in navbar */}
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav btn-toolbar">
            <li className="btn-group">
              <p className="navbar-btn text-uppercase">
                <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-default">Log In</a>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li className="btn-group">
              <p className="navbar-btn text-uppercase">
                <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <AuthModal />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you add your `<AuthModal />` component code?

Answer (score 1):

I see you're changing the mobx-state without the wrapped code being in an action function.

If a function changes the state, then it should be decorated as an `action`

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html

> Actions should only, and always, be used on functions that **modify state**. Functions that just perform look-ups, filters etc should not be marked as actions; to allow MobX to track their invocations.

Also, if the functions should be bound to the class, then you can use the decorator:

```
@action.bound
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

answer was provided here:
https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/829

use this:

```
<a onClick={() => this.props.authModalStore.changeToTab(2)}>Not a member yet?</a>
<a onClick={() => this.props.authModalStore.changeToTab(3)} className="pull-right">Forgot password?</a>
```

instead of

```
<a onClick={this.props.authModalStore.changeToTab(2)}>Not a member yet?</a>
<a onClick={this.props.authModalStore.changeToTab(3)} className="pull-right">Forgot password?</a>
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Any other suggestions?
I have an observable array in my store. I have added few items and when i try to update one of them using the button click event I get this error

Comment: you probably should open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change something in your store you need to use `action` as mobx state [here](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html)

Your import should look like this:

```
import { action, observable } from 'mobx';
```

Your function should look like this:

```
@action
turnOn(key = 1) {
  console.log('running turnOn');
  this.tab = key;
  this.show = true;
}
```

In **Mobx** you cannot mutate the `observable` outside the `action`.